# How to make decision boundary plots from RandomForest in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, random-forest

I would like to make a decision boundary plot in R, similar to the one below, representing decision boundaries for classification results from a Random Forest. I would like to be able to tweak and customize it, in something like ggplot.

[image]

This example is from RF classification of three classes from three predictors PC. I know that the starting points are scatterplots, the hard part is to recreate the maps. Appreciate any pointers

Comment: Here's a package you might consider. The readme doesn't show any figures, unfortunately, but it might work for you. https://github.com/ehrlinger/ggRandomForests#readme

Comment: @markhogue just had a look but unfortunately seems to be a dead_end documentation is scarce and most functions documented don't seem to exist

Comment: I installed the package and it seems to work just fine. It includes an extensive vignette.

Comment: thanks, but I don't see anywhere in the package a function to plot decision boundaries or anything close to it, which is the main issue I have, not fitting the models per se

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need any additional packages here. We can draw the boundary using only ggplot and randomForest.

Suppose we use the simple example of classifying the iris data set according to petal width and length:

```r
library(randomForest)

rf <- randomForest(Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris, 
                   proximity = TRUE)
```

Now we just create a grid of all x, y values in the range of the data using `expand.grid`, and get the predicted species at each pair:

```
df <- expand.grid(Petal.Width = seq(0, 3, length.out = 100),
                  Petal.Length = seq(0, 7, length.out = 100))

df$Species <- predict(rf, df)
```

Now we plot the boundary with `geom_raster`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_raster(data = df, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks for this, while it seems to work (thus I accepted), I am observing some discrepancies when I compare to a plot from another function. specifically when I use a dataset to classify 3 classes from 3 variables. The filled background seems not to represent well the classification of certain classes. I can't work out where the differences come from as I don't have the source code of the other tool which I am using for comparison

Comment: With 3 predictors, a 2D plot can only show a single "slice" of the decision boundary, which will be a complex 3D structure, so I should not be too surprised that the boundary plot doesn't appear to fit the points too well. Perhaps try plotting the first two components of a PCA as in your own example using the above method?

Comment: yeah, I get that, the issue doesn't have t do with 2d vs 3d I don't think. I plotted a series of 2D pairwise maps for var1 vs var 2, var 1, vs var 3 and var 2 vs var 3. The differences appear in any of those plots produced using JASP (the other tool), vs is I do the same with the code above. trying to figure our, so far I suspect it may have to do with the length.out argument, as the more I increase this using your solution, the closer the result looks to the JASP plot